# Node JS - how to detect user language

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to check user language in pure node js, without any extensions from npm.
I used process and global command, there is a lot of specifications but i couldn't find system language

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer is in your question. You don't want to use a plugin, but you can take a look on [how they do it](https://github.com/sindresorhus/os-locale/blob/master/index.js) :)

The answer is the `environment`

**Spoiler**

```
function getEnvLocale(env) {
    env = env || process.env;

    return env.LC_ALL || env.LC_MESSAGES || env.LANG || env.LANGUAGE;
}
```

---

Don't forget to adapt to the different platform *(mac, linux, windows...)*

Comment: Another env variable you might have missed (Linux Mint 18): `LC_NAME: 'en_ZA.UTF-8`

Comment: This is the only one of the answers that works in Windows.

Comment: i tried to use this and it worked for me, now just suddenly does not, none of them defined, i just get undefined from it :(. Testing on Windows 10, node 16.3.0

Comment: This is effectively not working on Windows 10/11.

Answer (score 41):

Here is an OS/node/browser independent way of obtaining the default locale

```js
let locale = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().locale;
console.log(locale);
```

Comment: Interesting, in the browser the value is different from navigator.language.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get user's OS language you can try to get it from environment:

```
const env = process.env;
const language = env.LANG || env.LANGUAGE || env.LC_ALL || env.LC_MESSAGES;
```

In most cases `process.env.LANG` should work. It will contain ISO 639-1 language code, ISO 3166-1 country code and encoding name.

Examples: `en_US.UTF-8`, `uk_UA.UTF-8`

However it can be overriden by different environment variables like `LC_ALL`, `LC_MESSAGES` etc.

Here is the description for `LANG` env variable from [Linux Manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html):

> The name of a locale to use for locale categories when not
>   overridden by LC_ALL or more specific environment variables
>   such as LC_COLLATE, LC_CTYPE, LC_MESSAGES, LC_MONETARY,
>   LC_NUMERIC, and LC_TIME.

Comment: It's works but only on linux or mac. 
Is there something similar for windows ?

Comment: As far as i know, there is no environment variable or even a CLI command to get the locale on Windows. Maybe this question will help https://serverfault.com/questions/173630/how-to-get-system-locale-in-windows-7-cmd/173689

Comment: Is this not the server side language you would get with this?

Answer (score 0):

To determine the user's language in pure Node.js without using any npm packages, you can leverage the environment variables. The accepted answer provides a function to fetch the language from environment variables. Here's a more concise one-liner:

```
const getEnvLocale = (env = process.env) => env.LC_ALL || env.LC_MESSAGES || env.LANG || env.LANGUAGE || 'en_US';
```

This function checks various environment variables (LC_ALL, LC_MESSAGES, LANG, and LANGUAGE) and defaults to 'en_US' if none is found.