# How can I get current system language in vue.config.js?

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I have a vue project,I want to set some build params to different language according to current system language,so How can i get current system language in vue.config.js?

Comment: What's the system you are using?

Comment: Current language of which system? It will be the language of your OS if you run it locally, and the language of a server if it runs remotely.

Comment: @EmīlsGulbis I'm using windows 10.

Comment: @EstusFlask Both my local and remote server are windows 10 machines.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58651429/8145128

Comment: It's unclear what's the intention. If it's a system you're aware of and the language isn't changed constantly, you could just set the desired language in env variable. Any way, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53094975/vue-js-defining-computed-environment-variables-in-vue-config-js-vue-cli-3  and https://github.com/sindresorhus/os-locale